# Is it possible to map a list of fields in a Play/Scala form

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

Given some object that has the ability to query its fields, is it possible to iterate over the fields to generate a list of mappings and to use the list of mappings to create a form?

For example:

```
class SomeModel ...

val model = new SomeModel

val mappings = model.fields { f =>
    f.fieldName -> text  // Just use String/text mappings to simplify the example   
  }

// Assuming 'of' is the correct mapping to use, What should be
// specified for <?1>, <?2> and <?3>
val form = Form(
    of( <?1> , <?2> ) {
        <?3>
      }
  )
```

Background:
I need to build a basic crud interface for our data model which consists of a 100+ tables, some with up to a 100 columns. Refactoring the data model is not an option since this crud interface is just one of many other users of the data. We generate the model classes so it is possible to also generate the form classes but I am hoping that I can get around the 18 / 22 field limit by using a list of fields instead.

Comment: are you using case classes for your models?

Comment: Unfortunately not - many tables have more than 22 columns and case classes can only have up to 22 fields (Scala 2.11 apparently supports more). The class structure is not really the issue here. The bottom line is: can I create a generic form from a list of fields without having to specify the fields at compile time.